# restarting sslsocketconnector after putting a new socket in truststore on jetty

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, jmx

I have a jetty webserver. I am trying to register a certificate into the truststore.

The certificate gets registered properly but when a client tries to authenticate with a registered certificate the certificate is not found in the trust store.

However the certificate is in the truststore but hasn't been loaded by jetty.

Same problem occurs in tomcat but then in tomcat when I restart the COnnectorMBean using jmx it starts to work.

Now in jetty when I restart the sslsocketconnector using JMX, it gets restarted but the connection breaks so I can't reload the certificate and then send a message back to the client after loading the certificate from the truststore.

I am trying to restart sslsocketconnector using the following code

```
 try{
           MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            Set names = mBeanServer.queryNames(new ObjectName("*:*"), null);

             Iterator it=names.iterator();
             while( it.hasNext()) {
                ObjectName oname= (ObjectName)it.next();

                MBeanInfo minfo = mBeanServer.getMBeanInfo(oname);



                if (minfo.getClassName().equals("org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector")) {
                    System.out.println("found ssl socket connector... will try to restart it");

                         System.out.println("Restarting SSL Connector on port ");
                         Object params[] = {};
                         String signature[] = {};
                         ;
                         /**
                          * Stop and restart the connector to get it to re-read the certificate trustfile
                          */
                         mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "stop", params, signature);
                         mBeanServer.invoke(oname, "start", params, signature);

                      }
                   }
                }
        catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Did not restart SSL Connector: " + e);
             e.printStackTrace();
             throw e;
          }
```

Can anybody tell me a good way to reload certificate in truststore without restarting the server and breaking the existing socket??

Thanks